# C - 2D Array malloc/free - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I have a very simple snippet below for which I am trying to figure out the reason for getting a segmentation fault.

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int size = 2;
    char** test1 = NULL;
    int index = 0;

    test1=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    if (test1 != NULL)
    {
            for (index = 0; index < size ; index++)
            {
                    test1[index]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
                    test1[index]='a';
            }

            //Removing this block does not result in seg fault - start
            for (index = 0 ; index < size ; index++)
            {
                    free(test1[index]); //Seg. fault here
            }
            //Removing this block does not result in seg fault - end

            free(test1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the block enclosed within start and end comment - I do not see seg fault. But I think that would result in a leak.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're assigning `'a'` to a variable you have declared as a charaacter pointer. in other words, `test[index] = 'a'` replaces a pointer that was allocated from the heap with the character `'a'`. Then you try to free `'a'` (since that's the value of `test[index]` in `free(test[index])`) as if it were an allocated pointer. That's a problem. I'm supposing you really meant, `*test[index] = 'a'`.

Comment: or `char *test1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);`.. `test1[index]='a';`.. `free(test1);`

Comment: Jeez...that was the issue - shold have been *test1[index]. Thanks a lot BLUEPIXY

Comment: or `test1[index]='a';` change to `test1[index][0]='a';`

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to dereference the test1[index]. Your code overwrites the address of the allocated memory with 'a', hence when it tries to free the memory it segs fault because 'a' is not a valid address.

```
test1[index]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
*test1[index]='a';
```

This works as well

```
test1[index][0]='a';
```

Answer (score 0):

You start out fine:

```
test1=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    if (test1 != NULL) {
```

Your loop is not:

```
        for (index = 0; index < size ; index++) {
                test1[index]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
                test1[index]='a';
        }
```

First, you allocating only one byte for what is supposed to be a row of characters (since you have only one "size" variable, I assume you want your 2d array to be square: 2x2. So you need to multiply by size here like you did in the outer loop. You *don't* need "sizeof(char)", that's just a long-winded way of typing "1".

But worse than that, after allocating the row too short, you then throw that memory away by overwriting the pointer with a character (you should have gotten a compiler warning here). That's disaster waiting to happen and  a memory leak.

What you really mean is:

```
        for (index = 0; index < size ; index++) {
                test1[index]=malloc(size);
                test1[index][0]='a';
        }
```